# Jquery Slider with background color change

Tags: jquery, css, transition

I'm using a slider that I found at http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ItemSlider/. I've modified the slider to change the background color to match the navigation text box color.

```
.tab1 {background:#A90000;width:100%;height:300px;color:#fff}
.tab2 {background:#2D4186;width:100%;height:300px;}
.tab3 {background:#ccc;width:100%;height:300px;}
.tab4 {background:#000;width:100%;height:300px;}

.mi-slider nav a.navtab1.mi-selected  {
color: #fff!important;
background:#A90000!important;
}
.mi-slider nav a.navtab2.mi-selected  {
color: #fff!important;
background:#2D4186!important;
}
.mi-slider nav a.navtab3.mi-selected  {
color: #fff!important;
background:#ccc!important;
}
.mi-slider nav a.navtab4.mi-selected  {
color: #fff!important;
background:#000!important;
}
```

The first round through, everything works, but when the slider tries to reset back to the first slide, or when a different text box is clicked, the background does not reset and match up.

The red text box should go with the red slider, blue with blue, etc. See this Fiddle that shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/gandjyar/6CUtH/4/

I think it's something simple, but I can't see it.

Suggestions?

Comment: None of them are working for me, it's only showing the red and no other